# Forked a repo using the website, made edits, now I'm getting conflict and can't merge

Tags: git

how can I fix this? I have both git gui/git bash but I had made previous edits using the web interface. A file I was editing got updated before my pull request got merged. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a special situation. Just normal conflict.

Let's name your Pull Request branch branch-x and name Pull Request destination branch master.

```
git checkout branch-x
git merge origin/master
git push origin branch-x
```

Now your Pull Request will be able to be merged.